# How can I provide meaningful error feedback from validation without side effects?

Tags: java, validation, rest

I'm trying to figure out a clean way to manage validation of REST endpoints that will allow me to provide meaningful feadback to the user in case of an error (HTTP status code and some error message) while at the same time avoiding side effects in the validation methods which are also performing work.

For instance, I need to parse a json object coming in, first I need to validate that it parses and get the object that represents it.  If I get an exception during parsing then I want to tell that to the user but I also want to get the object back from the validation method if it parses correctly.

There are two concerns here, validation and translating a json string into a POJO.  If I put them in the same method then how to I return the error string if the parsing fails without having a side effect?

Super pseudo-code showing one possibility, but with a side-effect:

```
public Pet parsePet(HTTPResponse httpResponse, String petStr) {
    Pet pet = null;
    try {
        Parser parser = new Parser();
        pet = parser.parse(petStr, Pet.class);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        httpResponse.setStatus(400);
    }
    return pet;
}
```

Obviously in this case I could use a null response to determine that it didn't parse and avoid the side-effect, but in a more complex example where different errors would produce different error status' how can I avoid side effects?

Is there some standard best practice or architectural concept for this sort of thing?

The "cleanest" option I could think of is to throw some new exception like `ValidationException(int statusCode)` that could be thrown when a business rule is broken.  But then the whole "exceptions are for exceptional things" comes into play.  Given that I'm ultimately returning an error to the user, it seems that an exception is somewhat acceptable here though.

Comment: You may declare wrapper class that will include object itself and validation/processing result (it may be an exception or some other type, for example, list of JSON elements that failed to validate).

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking for.  Where is the side effect in this method?  Is it on the `pet = ` part?  That won't necessarily have a side effect.  It depends on where it errors.

Comment: The side effect is that you are modifying the httpResponse inside of the method but not returning that object.

Answer (score 0):

> If I put them in the same method then how to I return the error string if the parsing fails without having a side effect?

Throw an exception when an error happens.  Something higher up will interpret it and convert it into a http error response.

Something else you could do that comes from the Haskell world is have this method return an `Either<Pet, Error>`.  One of these two (`Pet` or `Error`) will be filled in.  The caller needs to figure out which one.  I'm just giving you an option here, this is not something I've seen in idiomatic Java code.

> The "cleanest" option I could think of is to throw some new exception like `ValidationException(int statusCode)`

I think it would be a smidgen cleaner to throw a `PetParsingException` and something higher up interprets the exception and decides that it's a 400.  Your validation doesn't *have* to know that it's part of a restful api.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new interface that is used to store errors:

```
interface ValidationErrors 
{
    public void addError(String message); 
    public List<String> getErrors(); 
}
```

Change your parsePet method to accept an object of ValidationErrors instead of HTTPResponse.

```
public Pet parsePet(String petStr, ValidationErrors errors) {
    try {
        Parser parser = new Parser();
        pet = parser.parse(petStr, Pet.class);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        errors.addError("Parsing pet failed: " + e.getMessage());
        return null; 
    }

    return pet;
}
```

You can then implement a method to convert the ValidationErrors object into the appropriate HTTPResponse configuration.

ValidationErrors can grow with your needs - i. e. maybe you want to store the Exceptions in there, provide summaries of the errors encountered, or use automatic logging.

PS: Spring validators use a similar approach.

Comment: This does not solve the issue of side effects it only changes the object you're modifying.  Though I suppose instead of an interface you could create an abstract class and have some 'error' object containing the error.  You could then have your validation class extend the abstract class and modify, effectively, it's own internal state, which at some point may become invalid.

Comment: You can always move the errors into the returned result. I. e. create a class ValidationResult<T> that holds the list of errors and the correctly typed result T. 

Or, split validation and calculation into two different functions. validatePetJson to retrieve the list of possible errors, and only call parsePet once that succeed. There might be a performance hit if you need to parse twice. 

I guess it comes down to whether parse errors are unforseen (in which case the exceptions work well), or an expected output of your functions (in which case I'd either split or have a combined result).

Answer (score 0):

Throw the exception out of the business method (probably wrapped in some ValidationException with additional details) and let it be handled at a higher level up the method invocation stack.

The 'higher level' will in practice be some web framework error handling utility. There you can decide what to do with error - return a message with appropriate HTTP status, retry the operation or something else.

This will make the code much cleaner (the exceptions have been invented for that purpose) and it will actually help you to avoid undesirable side-effects (by rolling back transactions and similar).